# Disable CSRF for posts in sails for every route from one Controller

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, sails.js, csrf

I'm trying to disable CSRF from every Route to on Action from my Controller. So when i post to /offer/city every route contains that should be disabled (like /offer/city/Frankfurt)
In the config/csrf.js i already tried:

```
    module.exports.csrf = {
    grantTokenViaAjax: true,
    origin: '',
    routesDisabled: '/offer/city/..,/offer/city/,/offer/city'
};
```

but it doesn't work. Any Suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: why would you ever want to do that? Sounds like an X-Y problem

Comment: That's not true. when building mobile applications at times we need to disable CSRF for an entire controller. Certainly some use cases there.